# nginx rule - match all paths except one

Tags: nginx, regex

I am trying to match all paths that begin with /newsletter/ except one (/newsletter/one) with a regex.
What I have so far:

```
   location ~ ^/newsletter/(.*)$ {
// configuration here
}
```

This matches all the paths that begin with /newsletter/.

How do I make an exception for the path /newsletter/one ?

Comment: If you're googling this for Let's Encrypt, [here's how to set it up](https://github.com/letsencrypt/acme-spec/issues/221#issuecomment-168683597)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I ended up using the following solution:

```
location ~ ^/newsletter/(.*)$ {
    location ~ /newsletter/one(.*) {
           // logic here
    }
    // logic here
}
```

This matches all the paths under /newsletter/* and then I match all the paths that begin with /newsletter/one and apply the configuration for the newsletter/one in the inner configuration block while I keep the rest of the configuration in the outer configuration block.

Comment: Afaik a little bit of textual explanation could help a lot.

Answer (score 14):

This works but has one flaw. It will also not match on "one" followed by any characters.

```
location ~ ^/newsletter/(?!one).*$ {
    //configuration here
}
```

Although, this may be better:

```
location = /newsletter/one {
    // do something (not serve an index.html page)
}

location ~ ^/newsletter/.*$ {
    // do something else
}
```

This works because when Nginx finds an exact match with an `=` it uses that `location` to serve the request. One problem is that this will not match if you are using an `index` page because the request is rewritten internally and so will match the second `location` "better" and use that. See the following: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms#matching-location-blocks

There is a section which explains how Nginx chooses which location to use.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify on varlogtim's solution the following would work, allowing you to match on `/newsletter/one-time` but still skip `/newsletter/one`

`location ~ ^/newsletter/(?!one$).*$`

Also, if you want ignore case in your match, use the `~*` modifier in place of `~`

Answer (score 1):

Use negative match, like this:

```
    location ~* \.(php|png)/(?!(topic|news)) {
        return 410; # Gone
        break;
    }
```

This allows to emit a 410 Gone HTTP code except for the URIs with "topic" and "news" after the script name and a slash. This is handy if you want to prevent PHP scripts run by default but keep a **whitelist** of "safe" URIs that do actually require parameters in form of extra URI path.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the one:

```
^/newsletter(/&/[^o][^n][^e])$
```